# Sqlite delete query error

Tags: sqlite

```
 delete N.* from Tbl_Nodes N, Data_Tree DT WHERE N.Part = DT.Part
```

for this command I am getting following error.

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQLite error near "N": syntax error
```

Above command works fine for MSAccess.

Is there any alternative to use table shortcut in Sqlite?

Comment: That's some rather non-standard SQL. What does `WHERE N.Part` mean, and how are Tbl_Nodes and Data_Tree correlated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DELETE statement operates on a *single* table and does not use a table alias.  Therefore, your FROM clause must read `FROM Tbl_Nodes`.

You're probably looking for:

```
 delete from Tbl_Nodes WHERE Part IN (SELECT Part FROM Data_Tree)
```

Note that this will remove *all* nodes from Tbl_Nodes that have a corresponding `Part` value in `Data_Tree` but does not remove any records from `Data_Tree` itself.

While SQL varies somewhat among vendors, as a general principle it's a mistake to learn SQL from MS Access and try to apply it to other products.  MS Access features some very non-standard constructions.

Comment: +1 for the only solution so far that even stands a chance of being correct (as opposed to a syntax error!) SQLite sticks much closer to the SQL standard in much of its syntax than most databases.

Comment: the actual alias syntax `table AS alias` works with DELETE. It's just when you've forgotten more compatible SQL syntax and you do `table alias` where it fails on DELETE. Weirdly, it does work in SELECTs.

Answer (score 1):

Using an alias for the table?

```
FROM table AS t1
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a bit of your SQL statement there I guess but does it not work if you just say:

`delete N from Tbl_Nodes N, Data_tree DT WHERE...(rest of statement)`

I've just removed the .*

Comment: From what I find on the sqlite site it seems that doing deletes against joins as you can in other DB products is not supported. The Larry Lustig answer should work for you though.